# Discord.js remove role of user from a specific guild

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a membership bot for Discord. The bot will retrieve an user ID and a role from the API and needs to remove this role from the user.

First I am getting the guild where the specific user is in:

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('842361027562831872');
```

Then I am finding the role by the name:

```
let role = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Sport");
if (!role) return;
```

Then I am trying to find the user by his ID, and remove the above role. However the user is always undefined:

```
guild.members.cache.get(user.user).roles.remove(role);
```

Normally when I add a role I use the message Object and then use the guild from that message like this:

```
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Sport");
if (!role) return;
message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id).roles.add(role);
```

However I retrieve the data from an API so I have to do it another way.

The full code of my script:

```
get('/expired', '', function (result) {
            let users = result.data.users;
            const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('842361027562831872');

            users.forEach(user => {

                let role = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === user.role);
                if (!role) return;

                guild.members.cache.get(user.user).roles.remove(role);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I had to use the fetch method which then returns a promise.

```
guild.members.fetch(user.user).then(member => {
     member.roles.remove(role);
     member.send(`Your subscription for ${user.role} is expired.`);
}).catch(console.log);
```

I then can remove the role of that user and send him/her a direct message.